# TRAC 0.12 buildout error - no attribute 'env_open'

Tags: python, trac, buildout

I am trying to use Tarek Ziadé's Trac [buildout recipe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbp.recipe.trac/0.2.2) from [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) (and his book '[Expert Python Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/184719494X?ie=UTF8&tag=mophosandphot-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=184719494X)', which I don't have access to.)

It worked fine the first time round, however upon creating a new (Python 2.6 virtualenv) environment I got the following error on buildout.

```
File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/pbp.recipe.trac-0.2.3-py2.6.egg/pbp/recipe/trac/__init__.py", line 59, in install
    milestone_list = [m.name for m in Milestone.select(trac.env_open())]

AttributeError: TracAdmin instance has no attribute 'env_open'
```

Sure enough, if i insert a pdb.set_trace() before [line 59](http://bitbucket.org/tarek/atomisator/src/tip/packages/pbp.recipe.trac/pbp/recipe/trac/__init__.py) and introspect `trac` then I can see there is no `env_open` attribute (although there is `env_set`, `env_check` etc).

The one time it did work was in a very messy development environment that already had one (non buildout) Trac instance set up and had been built with sudo permissions (the newer environment has normal permissions).

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, although, based on the above, it feels like the recipe is trying to open a trac instance that doesnt exist yet or it can't access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pbp.recipe.trac 0.4.0 was just released and add full support of Trac 0.12: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbp.recipe.trac/0.4.0 .

Comment: I haven't tested this yet (I've moved on from this particular project), but if it works as advertised it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be caused by a change made between Trac 0.11 and 0.12.

Setting the following in the buildout file, will result in a successful build.

```
[buildout]
versions = versions
parts = trac
index = http://pypi.python.org/simple

[versions]
Trac = 0.11

[trac]
etc....
```

However, I will leave the question open, as I would like the buildout to eventually work with 0.12 too.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I've recently updated the pbp.recipe.trac recipe to have full support of Trac 0.11. See: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbp.recipe.trac/0.3.0 .

Trac 0.12 support is coming soon. Tests, feature requests and contributions are welcomed ! :)